# Django not rendering form fields

Tags: python, django

I looked at similar questions but they do not seem to apply. I have a very simple django form which does not show on the website, I only see the Submit button. Here are the relevant files:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
import uuid

# Create your models here.
class Job(models.Model): 
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #One to many relationship requires on_delete
    email = models.EmailField()
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.job_name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
class JobForm(forms.Form):
    job_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

***views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import JobForm
from .models import Job

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

class SubmitPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'submit.html'


def submit_job(request):
    # Retrieve post by id
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # Form was submitted
        form = JobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
    #Form fields passed validation
    #If the form is valid, we retrieve the validated data accessing
    #form.cleaned_data. This attribute is a dictionary of form fields and their values.
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            my_model = Job()
            my_model.job_name = cd.get('job_name')
            my_model.email = cd.get('email')
            # Save the job to the database
            my_model.save()
    else:
        form = JobForm()
    return render(request, SubmitPageView(), {'form': form})
```

And in my template I have

```
         <form method="POST" action=".">
            <table>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_table }}
            </table>
```

which gets rendered as:

```
          <form method="POST" action=".">
            <table>
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="I7yL9XAUhEPiriKVHKtqh9UfhsLWoJrBo68uguqMecX8gmuNoJV7gykvsPc7FtQ2">

            </table>
```

Comment: wait a minute. Do you need the <table> tag?  Doesn't form.as_table render all appropriate tags for you?

Comment: From Django docs: "{{ form.as_table }} will render them as table cells wrapped in <tr> tags". Anyway, it is defo not the issue here, I tried form.as_p with no success.

Comment: next question: do you have a close form tag?  (You didn't include one in your template code.)

Comment: Yes, and a submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution by following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/
Basically, as I was using class-based views, the functions to get and post the form need to be subsumed into the class-based view for that page. Here is the current version
of **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import JobForm
from .models import Job

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

class SubmitPageView(TemplateView):
    form_class = JobForm
    template_name = 'submit.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
    #Form fields passed validation
    #If the form is valid, we retrieve the validated data accessing
    #form.cleaned_data. This attribute is a dictionary of form fields and their values.
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            my_model = Job()
            my_model.job_name = cd.get('job_name')
            my_model.email = cd.get('email')
            # Save the job to the database
            my_model.save()
        else:
            form = JobForm()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = JobForm()

    return render(request, 'submit.html', {'form': form})


<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, does not make a difference - tried this before.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make a difference if you define the form as a modelForm and explicitly state the model and fields?

Add/modify the following to your Forms.py:

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Job
    fields = ('job_name', 'email')
  job_name = forms....
```

Comment: I tried avoiding using ModelForm as I will need to do some form data preprocessing before loading into database for other fields. However, changing this to ModelForm like above does not solve my problem. I must be missing something really obvious :(.